# can not locate JDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, xamarin

I can't locate my JDK. What I've done is changed the default location because I saw it as one of solution to "non working SDK manager" as it said java path should not contain spaces soo i created a new map on j: disk and moved the java directory and also changed the JAVA_HOME  variable each time i moved the jdk. Since it wasn't working that way either i tried to change it all back to old "Program Files" path but then i got to this problem, I've been trying to resolve this for past few days for like 6 hours a day and I am all out of the options, please don't redirect me to the "similar" post cause i tried googling for everything.I am using Xamarin IDE and win7 -32bit.

I also tried:
- reinstalling SDK manager wich worked for like 5 mins ,I could have use it but then after I've updated some of the SDK packages he was gone. 
-installing jdk 1.8.0_20 and 1.8.0_39 
-using the CMD

Comment: did you uninstall everything already?

Comment: no, i don't know how to uninstall JDKs , and should i uninstall SDK manager too , and Xamarin?

Comment: I would uninstall everything and start over. https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html there is a guide to uninstalling and installing jdk over again.

Comment: I will try that right now, can i also install jdk in non default folder?

Comment: why not just put in default?

Comment: cause there are bunch of posts out there saying java can't find a path if there is a space in there like "Program Files"

Comment: I have mines in the Program Files and it works fine

Comment: ok thank you i am installing JDK now

Comment: I always keep it under Program Files and have never run into any problems.

Answer (score 0):

### Uninstall everything Java:

Run "Control Panel" ⇒ Program and Features ⇒ Un-install programs begin with "Java", such as "Java SE Development Kit" and "Java SE Runtime". If you are not sure whether you have older version(s) of JDK, check!

### Install Java

1. Goto Java SE download site @
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.
2. Under "Java SE 8ux", click the "Download" button under "JDK". Check
   "Accept License Agreement". Choose your operating platform, e.g.,
   Windows x86 for 32-bit Windows OS or Windows x64 for 64-bit Windows
   OS.
3. You can check whether your Windows OS is 32-bit or 64-bit via
   "Control Panel" ⇒ System ⇒ Under the "System Type".

Full instructions can be found here:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html

### Install Android SDK

The Android SDK contains all the tools and frameworks needed for developing an Android application. There are a number of steps needed to install it correctly, which are described below:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

### Install Xamarin

After all the building blocks have been installed, it’s time for us to install our IDE. When using Windows you have a choice of IDE – Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio, we recommend having both. In this section we will look at installing Xamarin Studio.

Xamarin Studio is an open-source Integrated Development Environment (IDE) designed for building Mono-based applications.

Xamarin should pick up your only JDK if everything installed properly.

Comment: ok i am on Android SDK stepp now , should i remove the old one (non working ) first and about the xamarin, when uninstalling it. Do i uninstall the xamarin studio or the whole xamarin from the control panel?

Comment: do everything so its a completely clean install

Comment: is it a problem if Android SDK manager Log opened in the middle of installation proccess of chosen SDK Tools . There is one red marked message saying: "Stopping ADB server failed (code -1)"

Comment: everything is installer and SDK manager doesn't want to start up again. I need a higher lvl API to test my app on ,I only got lvl 11 and 12